# Source of market or security attribute information?

Tags: futures, bloomberg, exchange

There are many securities and exchanges on platforms like Bloomberg and Quandl, but many securities are described with the relevant pit close times and pit open times, exchanges, related futures, and settlement procedures.

Is there a reliable source where people go to find these things out? Kind of like a one stop shop.

Answer (score 1):

People often use Compustat or FactSet for high-level data like that.